# Linux cannot install anything E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I cannot install anything via terminal. For example I want to install Synaptic package manager. I run `sudo apt-get install synaptic` or `sudo apt-get -f install synaptic` and get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aglfn chktex cm-super cm-super-minimal context context-modules cups-browsed
  cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters-core-drivers cups-server-common
  dvidvi dvipng feynmf fonts-cabin fonts-comfortaa fonts-dejavu
  fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-ebgaramond fonts-ebgaramond-extra
  fonts-font-awesome fonts-freefont-otf fonts-gfs-artemisia
  fonts-gfs-baskerville fonts-gfs-bodoni-classic fonts-gfs-complutum
  fonts-gfs-didot fonts-gfs-didot-classic fonts-gfs-gazis
  fonts-gfs-neohellenic fonts-gfs-olga fonts-gfs-porson fonts-gfs-solomos
  fonts-gfs-theokritos fonts-hosny-amiri fonts-junicode fonts-linuxlibertine
  fonts-lobster fonts-lobstertwo fonts-oflb-asana-math fonts-roboto-hinted
  fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic fonts-sil-gentiumplus
  fonts-texgyre fragmaster hplip-data icoutils imagemagick-6.q16 kactivities
  kate-data katepart kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kde-style-breeze
  kde-style-breeze-qt4 kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools
  kpackagelauncherqml kpackagetool5 kwayland-data kwayland-integration lacheck
  latexdiff latexmk lcdf-typetools libattica0.4 libcupscgi1 libcupsmime1
  libdlrestrictions1 libfam0 libfile-homedir-perl libfile-which-perl
  libfontembed1 libgutenprint2 libhpmud0 libkactivities6
  libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5
  libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4
  libkf5activities5 libkf5archive5 libkf5attica5 libkf5auth-data libkf5auth5
  libkf5calendarevents5 libkf5codecs-data libkf5codecs5 libkf5completion-data
  libkf5completion5 libkf5config-bin libkf5config-data libkf5configcore5
  libkf5configgui5 libkf5configwidgets-data libkf5configwidgets5
  libkf5coreaddons-data libkf5coreaddons5 libkf5crash5 libkf5dbusaddons-bin
  libkf5dbusaddons-data libkf5dbusaddons5 libkf5declarative-data
  libkf5declarative5 libkf5globalaccel-bin libkf5globalaccel-data
  libkf5globalaccel5 libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5guiaddons5
  libkf5i18n-data libkf5i18n5 libkf5iconthemes-bin libkf5iconthemes-data
  libkf5iconthemes5 libkf5idletime5 libkf5itemviews-data libkf5itemviews5
  libkf5jobwidgets-data libkf5jobwidgets5 libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiowidgets5
  libkf5notifications-data libkf5notifications5 libkf5package-data
  libkf5package5 libkf5plasma5 libkf5plasmaquick5 libkf5quickaddons5
  libkf5service-bin libkf5service-data libkf5service5 libkf5sonnet5-data
  libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5style5 libkf5textwidgets-data
  libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5widgetsaddons-data
  libkf5widgetsaddons5 libkf5windowsystem-data libkf5windowsystem5
  libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data libkf5xmlgui5 libkfile4 libkhtml5
  libkidletime4 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4
  libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4
  libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 libkxmlrpcclient4
  liblouisutdml-bin liblouisutdml-data liblouisutdml6 libnetpbm10
  libnl-route-3-200 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libphonon4 libphonon4qt5-4
  libplasma3 libplot2c2 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpolkit-qt5-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-4
  libpstoedit0c2a libqca2 libqca2-plugins libqpdf17 libqt5quickwidgets5
  libqt5script5 libqtassistantclient4 libqtwebkit4 libsane-hpaio libsnmp-base
  libsnmp30 libsolid4 libstreamanalyzer0v5 libstreams0v5
  libtext-unidecode-perl libthreadweaver4 libvoikko1 libxcb-composite0
  libxcb-damage0 libxml-libxml-perl libxml-namespacesupport-perl
  libxml-sax-base-perl libxml-sax-expat-perl libxml-sax-perl netpbm
  ntrack-module-libnl-0 oxygen-icon-theme oxygen5-icon-theme pfb2t1c2pfb
  phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer phonon-backend-gstreamer-common
  plasma-framework plasma-scriptengine-javascript prerex preview-latex-style
  prosper pstoedit purifyeps python-kde4 python-pyudev python-qt4 python-sip
  python3-pexpect python3-pil python3-ptyprocess python3-renderpm
  python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel qml-module-org-kde-activities
  qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons
  qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-dialogs
  qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qpdf sonnet-plugins ssl-cert tex-gyre
  tex4ht tex4ht-common texinfo texlive-bibtex-extra texlive-extra-utils
  texlive-fonts-extra texlive-fonts-extra-doc texlive-fonts-recommended
  texlive-fonts-recommended-doc texlive-formats-extra texlive-games
  texlive-generic-extra texlive-generic-recommended texlive-htmlxml
  texlive-humanities texlive-humanities-doc texlive-lang-african
  texlive-lang-arabic texlive-lang-cyrillic texlive-lang-czechslovak
  texlive-lang-english texlive-lang-european texlive-lang-french
  texlive-lang-german texlive-lang-greek texlive-lang-indic
  texlive-lang-italian texlive-lang-polish texlive-lang-portuguese
  texlive-lang-spanish texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-extra-doc
  texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-luatex
  texlive-math-extra texlive-metapost texlive-metapost-doc texlive-music
  texlive-omega texlive-pictures texlive-pictures-doc texlive-plain-extra
  texlive-pstricks texlive-pstricks-doc texlive-publishers
  texlive-publishers-doc texlive-science texlive-science-doc texlive-xetex
  tipa ttf-adf-accanthis ttf-adf-gillius ttf-adf-universalis vprerex
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libept1.5.0 librarian0 rarian-compat
Suggested packages:
  dwww menu deborphan apt-xapian-index tasksel
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libept1.5.0 librarian0 rarian-compat synaptic
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
14 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1.537 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7.962 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libept1.5.0 amd64 1.1+nmu3 [77,6 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 librarian0 amd64 0.8.1-6 [50,4 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 rarian-compat amd64 0.8.1-6 [55,7 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 synaptic amd64 0.83 [1.354 kB]
Fetched 1.537 kB in 0s (1.570 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package libept1.5.0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 457302 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libept1.5.0_1.1+nmu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libept1.5.0:amd64 (1.1+nmu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package librarian0.
Preparing to unpack .../librarian0_0.8.1-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking librarian0 (0.8.1-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rarian-compat.
Preparing to unpack .../rarian-compat_0.8.1-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rarian-compat (0.8.1-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package synaptic.
Preparing to unpack .../synaptic_0.83_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking synaptic (0.83) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libgraph.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
Scrollkeeper was installed, forcing re-registration of all documents.
Unregistering 54 doc-base files, re-registering 54 doc-base files...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up imagemagick-common (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2) ...
dpkg: error processing package imagemagick-common (--configure):
 cannot compute MD5 hash for file '/etc/ImageMagick-6/thresholds.xml': failed to read (Input/output error)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickcore-6-arch-config:amd64:
 libmagickcore-6-arch-config:amd64 depends on imagemagick-common (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package imagemagick-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagickcore-6-arch-config:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickcore-6-headers:
 libmagickcore-6-headers depends on libmagickcore-6-arch-config (>= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6-arch-config:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagickcore-6-headers depends on libmagickcore-6-arch-config (<< 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2.1~); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6-arch-config:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagickcore-6-headers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64:
 libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 depends oNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                        n imagemagick-common (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package imagemagick-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64:
 libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.9.9); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 depends on imagemagick-common (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package imagemagick-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of imagemagick-6.q16:
 imagemagick-6.q16 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 imagemagick-6.q16 depends on libmagickwand-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2); however:
  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                              Package libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package imagemagick-6.q16 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickwand-6-headers:
 libmagickwand-6-headers depends on libmagickcore-6-headers (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6-headers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagickwand-6-headers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagick++-6-headers:
 libmagick++-6-headers depends on libmagickwand-6-headers (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickwand-6-headers is not configured yet.
 libmagick++-6-headers depends on libmagickcore-6-headers (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6-headers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagick++-6-headers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:amd64:
 libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.9.9); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:amd64 depends on libmagickwand-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.9); however:
  Package libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64:
 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.9.9); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 depends on libmagickwand-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2); however:
  Package libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickcore-6.q16-dev:amd64:
 libmagickcore-6.q16-dev:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6-headers (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6-headers is not configured yet.
 libmagickcore-6.q16-dev:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagickcore-6.q16-dev:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagickcore-6.q16-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickwand-6.q16-dev:amd64:
 libmagickwand-6.q16-dev:amd64 depends on libmagickwand-6-headers (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickwand-6-headers is not configured yet.
 libmagickwand-6.q16-dev:amd64 depends on libmagickwand-6.q16-2 (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagickwand-6.q16-dev:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagickwand-6.q16-dev:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-dev (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagickwand-6.q16-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagick++-6.q16-dev:amd64:
 libmagick++-6.q16-dev:amd64 depends on libmagick++-6-headers (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagick++-6-headers is not configured yet.
 libmagick++-6.q16-dev:amd64 depends on libmagick++-6.q16-5v5 (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagick++-6.q16-dev:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-dev (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagick++-6.q16-dev:amd64 depends on libmagickwand-6.q16-dev (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2); however:
  Package libmagickwand-6.q16-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagick++-6.q16-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagick++-dev:
 libmagick++-dev depends on libmagick++-6.q16-dev; however:
  Package libmagick++-6.q16-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagick++-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libept1.5.0:amd64 (1.1+nmu3) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up librarian0 (0.8.1-6) ...
Setting up rarian-compat (0.8.1-6) ...
Setting up synaptic (0.83) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libgraph.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Errors were encountered while processing:
 imagemagick-common
 libmagickcore-6-arch-config:amd64
 libmagickcore-6-headers
 libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64
 libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64
 imagemagick-6.q16
 libmagickwand-6-headers
 libmagick++-6-headers
 libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:amd64
 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64
 libmagickcore-6.q16-dev:amd64
 libmagickwand-6.q16-dev:amd64
 libmagick++-6.q16-dev:amd64
 libmagick++-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know how to fix it. I have seen many posts online which didn't help me further.

Thank you

Comment: Could you add the output of `ls -l /etc/ImageMagick-6/thresholds.xml; md5sum /etc/ImageMagick-6/thresholds.xml` , Open `gnome-disks`, from menu click *SMART Data & Self Tests..*, make screenshot and add it to the question.